# I'm having trouble grabbing a XML attachment and saving it to a Google drive folder

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, gmail, saving-data

When I looked online I found a script I have been using as a reference. I'm not able to get the copyBlob command to get the XML data I need. All I need is to get this attachment saved to a specific drive folder. I keep getting a Type error folder.CreateFiles isn't a function. I think I might have it worded wrong too because I believe it creates a folder in my drive and I just want it to save it to a specific folder. I'm just trying to get this material saved in a form that will be easy to reference later which is why I used the copyBlob. Am I missing something? I didn't think it would be this tricky just getting the attachment saved to a folder.

---

---

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1QTrx6_XXycHs8Wa3fiwEeXjN0qyWGypo');
  var userId = "abc123.@xxxx.com";
  var query = "label:ToBeProcessedByGAS";
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
  Logger.log(res);
  if(res.resultSizeEstimate >0){
    res.messages.forEach(function(m){
       var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
      Logger.log(attA)
      attA.forEach(function(a){
        var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyMMddHHmmss");
        folder.createFiles(blob()).setName(a.getName()+ts);
     });
    });
  }
};
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

### There are 2 issues in your current code:

1. You used [DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) which will return a [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) which is a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name it is somewhat an array of folders having the given name.

**Solution:**

If you already have a specific folder that you want to save your attachments, use [DriveApp.getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) instead. You just need to provide the folder id which you could obtain in the url link of your folder.

**Example Drive Folder URL:**

```
https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/1lFzVvlBnBi-2o1VQGF5JDFxxxxxxx?resourcekey=0-ovPPl55Wxxxxxxx
```

> Folder id will be the text after "folders/" and before "?" `https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/<Folder Id>?resourcekey=0-ovPPl55Wxxxxxxx`

2. Both [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) and [Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) don't have `createFiles()` method. It should be [Folder.createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob)

---

### Sample Code:

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1QHe2zCebXBZxiplAfVZpOxxxxxx');
  var userId = "abc123@xxxxx.com";
  var query = "label:ToBeProcessedByGAS";
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
  Logger.log(res);

  if(res.resultSizeEstimate >0){
    res.messages.forEach(function(m){
      var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
      Logger.log(attA);
      attA.forEach(function(a){
        var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyMMddHHmmss");
        folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName()+ts);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you update your latest code so i could check further?

Comment: This is amazing thanks! Those two parts finally work, but now it says can't read 'forEach' of undefined. I thought I had it defined by (m) in res.message.forEach(function(m)? What does this mean? yes I can

Comment: Yes, please update the latest code and include the complete error in the execution log

Comment: I updated it and heres the error code exactly                       TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
saveAttachmentInFolder

Comment: The error you encountered will happen when your `Gmail.Users.Messages.list()` request returns an empty search result, `messages` parameter in the response body will not be present. Hence there will be no such `res.messages` array.You can verify that by showing your `res` variable in the logs. You can check if `res.resultSizeEstimate >0 `before checking the message parameter. See the updated sample code in the answer

Comment: thank you so much! I am no longer getting an error code so I think it is fixed! Youve been a huge help, now I just need to do a quick run through and see if it pulls the attachments!

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: sorry when pulling the attachment from emails I get an error code, it says ReferanceError: blob is not defined. it also says theres a error on the res.message.forEach line again

Comment: why did you replaced your blob script when creating a file. it should be `a.copyBlob()`, See the sample code. When you inspect all your attachment list using `attA.forEach(function(a){ .. });`. You basically check each [GmailAttachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) using variable `a`. You did not define a `Blob()` in the first place. You need to use `copyBlob()` method available in the [GmailAttachment Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment)

Comment: oh ok my bad I see what you mean. I didnt realize I did that

Comment: You are a paragon among forum question answerers, thanks a million it now works!

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer